# convert date string to yyyy-mm-dd pragmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, date

I have written a very small, lightweight custom function that orders a table based on it's value. This function works on all columns and scales nicely.

The problem I have is when it comes to ordering by date. The data retrieved from the database (which cannot not be changed) is in the format dd-mm-yyyy. Obviously this is ordering by the first value, which will not give the desired result as `01-06-2016` should not become before `09-01-2016`.

I could write a seperate function that does various date conversions and comparisons but my attemps thus far have become very bloated. Almost becoming larger than the oringinal function. Could someone please suggest a clean way of doing this?

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/6sskjbod/565/

```
function sortTable(order, col) {
  var rows = $('#mytable tbody  tr').get();

  rows.sort(function(a, b) {

    var A = $(a).children('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();
    var B = $(b).children('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();

    if (order) {
      if (B < A) return -1;
      if (B > A) return 1;
    } else {
      if (A < B) return -1;
      if (A > B) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
  });

  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
  });
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `moment.js` ? Its one of the best libraries to do these kinda functions

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa thanks - but I don't want to use a library for a single use case.

Comment: I do not understand your question. do you mean you need to sort according to chronological order everytime ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ad a 'date' class to specific `th` and then deal with them differently within the function themselves. In this example i simply detec if it's a date value by checking the class and then reverse the values so it reads `yyyy-mm-dd`

https://jsfiddle.net/kplcode/2nvopbqo/1/

```
$(".sort").click(function() {
  var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
  var desc = $(this).hasClass('desc');
  var date = $(this).hasClass('date');
  sortTable(desc, col, date);
  $(this).toggleClass("desc asc");
});

function sortTable(order, col, date) {
  var rows = $('#mytable tbody  tr').get();

  rows.sort(function(a, b) {

    var A = $(a).children('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();
    var B = $(b).children('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();

    if(date) {
      var A = A.split("-").reverse().join('-');
        var B = B.split("-").reverse().join('-');
    }

    if (order) {
      if (B < A) return -1;
      if (B > A) return 1;
    } else {
      if (A < B) return -1;
      if (A > B) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
  });

  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
  });
}
```

Comment: If you are creating the string purely for the sake of comparison, then you can treat the date as a number and join with "": `a = a.split("-").reverse().join('')` then same for `b` and then simply return `a - b` or `(a - b) * -1` depending on the order.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to convert your date string to ISO format (`YYYY-MM-DD`) then you can simply convert it to a `Date` object.

Your jQuery sortTable function will look like this:

```
function sortTable(order, col) {
  var rows = $('#mytable tbody  tr').get();

  rows.sort(function(a, b) {
  var A,B;
 if(col==0)
 {
        valA = $(a).children('td').eq(col).text().split('-');
        valB = $(b).children('td').eq(col).text().split('-');
    A = new Date(valA[2]+"-"+valA[1]+"-"+valA[0]);
    B = new Date(valB[2]+"-"+valB[1]+"-"+valB[0]);;
 }
 else
 {
    A = $(a).children('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();
    B = $(b).children('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();
  }
    if (order) {
      if (B < A) return -1;
      if (B > A) return 1;
    } else {
      if (A < B) return -1;
      if (A > B) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
  });

  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
  });
}
```

Here is working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7jLvvp0n/2/

Comment: If converting to a Date (and there's no need to do that), then you can simply do `return A - B`. Your solution doesn't account for where `+A == +B`.

Comment: @RobG Not getting your point exactly, can you please elaborate more

Comment: You manually parse the string, then create another string, then parse that with the Date constructor (which is strongly not recommended). Use the values directly with the date constructor: `A = new Date(valA[2], valA[1]-1, valA[0])`. Then just do `return A - B` since the `-` operator coerces the Dates to their time value (so does the `<` operator). But anyway, you can just concatenate the date strings so `A=valA[2]+valA[1]+valA[0]`, do the same for with *B* and also `return A - B`. No Date required.

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding the dates to the html? If you are receiving the data and you know the current date value, you can easily reformat the date value like:

```
var parts = origDate.split('-');
var newFormat = parts[2] + '-' + parts[1] + '-' + parts[0];
```

before adding to the DOM.

Comment: Simpler: `origDate.split('-').reverse().join('-');`